Accessing CMFCButton from its member variable
I have a working modal MFC Dialog that will, at times, create a modal child dialog DJMB_Dlg. The child dialog window was created using the Dialog Editor in VS 2022. The child dialog window has a CMFCButton with a member variable (MB_can1_var) (both created with the IDE). I have also done:
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()  
CMyButton MB_can1_var; // member variable that was added w/wizard

If I use
BOOL DJMB_Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{   CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    MB_can1_var.Create(_T("My CButton"), 
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | 
        BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(10, 10, 100, 30), this, 
        IDC_DJ_MB_CANCEL1); 
    ...
} 

I get a NEW button and can use MB_can1_var.SetTextColor(...) and other functions.  But I cannot figure out how to use that member variable to do the same Set... function on my EXISTING (pre-defined) button. If I put those same function calls in the oninit for DJMB_Dlg, WITHOUT the Create, they get ignored. It seems I have not really built the connection between my pre-defined button and its member var. What do I not understand here??? The wizard did NOT add any code for my pre-defined button (nothing in the Message_Map either, yet the member var works with Create.
PS. Sorry about incorrect formatting. I had used backticks instead of GT.

Please format your question so as the code is in a code block. The existing button must be associated with a member variable of type CMFCButton or CMyButton, using the VS Class Wizard (Add Variable operation). It will add the code in the DoDataExchange() function.

See Dialog Data Exchange, and DDX_Control in particular. Consider getting a comprehensive book on MFC, like Prosise' Programming Windows with MFC.

This works since MFC V1.00. In the Dialog Editor select the control, right-click and select Add Variable. OR, right-click on the dialog and select Class Wizard, then go to Member Variables tab, highlight the control ID and click Add Variable. In the Category combo make sure you have selected Control. You must also specify the variable name and type - you can choose a type other than the default (a derived class), aka "subclassing". The wizard will add a DDX_Control() call in the DoDataExchange() function - this binds the control to the member variable.

You don't need to do Create because you already created the button on the resource editor.

You have your dialog open in the resource editor and drag a MFC button onto it.

Then, you right click the dialog and choose the option to add a class. By now you will have a dialog resource/class combination.

Right click the button and choose Add Variable. The pop will be set to Control. In most cases you set the scope to private. Give it a name, eg: m_mybutton.


That’s it. The system handles the rest and adds the required code to create the button and tie it to the variable.
Follow the same approach to map say an edit control to a control (CEdit) or a value (eg CString) or both.
If you assign a control to a value and give it private scope, then add public functions if needed to get / set the values. I expect there are many tutorials about it.

It should be noted that there are several ways to use the IDE to add the override like OnInitDialog too.
